# Android AsyncTask best practice / design paterns?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am not an experienced android developer, but I am as a programmer. I would like to get some advice on how to use AsyncTasks in android. I know how to implement them but what bothers me is that if I want to make results visible to UI I have to make changes to the UI from the AsyncTask. 
I do not like this since I imagine AsyncTask more or less as a thread for getting data or doing some computing. I tried to implement callback to the Activity which then changes UI. But I am not sure if this is a good practice.

Google docs says: "AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers."

In few words, I do not like for the AsyncTaks to change the UI. I see AsyncTask as something that gets data, and I see Activites as "controllers" for interacting with UI. Is there any good patterns to work with AsyncTasks? or more specific is it ok to make a calback in the onPostExecute to the main UI thread?

Comment: I know it is not what you asked but I strongly suggest NOT to use AsyncTask. Why? Because it is heavily coupled with your activity/fragment. Meaning that, if your activity/fragment changes it state (Paused,destroyed) your async task will get destroyed even if you didn't receive your results. A solution? I'd recommend using an EventBus (like Otto or GreenDao's Event Bus)

Comment: @LeonardoFerrari: An `AsyncTask` is not destroyed on a configuration change, or even the activity being destroyed via the BACK button.

Comment: "what bothers me is that if I want to make results visible to UI I have to make changes to the UI from the AsyncTask" -- no, you do not.
The only requirement is that you must update the UI from *the main application thread*. The `doInBackground()` method of the `AsyncTask` is a likely spot to trigger that UI update. How exactly you accomplish the UI update is up to you. "Is there any good patterns to work with AsyncTasks?" -- there are lots, and other patterns that do not use `AsyncTask`. You need to explain *a specific problem* first, though, as not all patterns are appropriate in all cases.

Comment: I added more specific question in the end about callback to the main UI thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You provided yourself with best practice explanation for AsyncTask:

*"AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers."*

To understand why and how does the AsyncTask operate as a background process while having the possibility to communicate with the UI thread let's take a look at this sample:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
             // Callback executed on UI thread right before starting the background process.
        }

        @Override
        protected  Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Background process execution.
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Callback executed on UI thread right after finishing the background process.
        }
    }.execute();
```

As explained by google, using this instead of a custom Thread/Task, removes the necessity of having to delegate on handlers and build up custom callbacks for UI thread interaction.

In Android, since most of the time that you need of a background process it is because you would want to deliver/manipulate it's results into an Activity (which runs on UI thread), AsyncTask provides such intercommunication before and after the process, with the possibility of parametrizing data for any of the callbacks.